# Transparent buttons on a background image

Tags: react-native

I have a problem when I put buttons on a background image, for some reason they are transparent and take the color of the background image, if I use the same button component somewhere else that is not on top of a background image the color button is not modified, this only happens when the button is on an image and only in android, someone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

add a TouchebleOpacity on ImageBackground component

Comment: when I add the "TouchebleOpacity" the buttons get out of place, and the image stops appearing